# Java Swing architecture for flipping through JPane based views

Tags: java, swing, architecture, layout

I have done a couple of simple swing based apps with static layout, but now I've run into a problem while trying to create an app containing multiple views which are changed by pressing appropriate navigational button.

You could compare the idea to a website so that every view has buttons to access certain other views but this would work inside a single JFrame.

I've found that maybe CardLayout ([Cardlayout example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)) might be appropriate solution for this kind of structure, but I'm unable to figure out a way to switch the views from the buttons which are inside of the JPanes that I've implemented in their separate classes,

Of course one way would be to instantiate everything in the parent class like in the small java tutorial example, but this isn't quite clean nor modular for multiple views, isn't it.

How can this be implemented so that I can access the view switching method?

Comment: Maybe something like JTabbedPane?

Comment: What are you trying to do, a kind of wizard? If so, there are a couple of open source libraries that could help you (but it's a long time I didn't check them out). Otherwise, if you need more possibilities (like several views at the same time), you may be then looking for a docking library. Please clarify further your problem.

Comment: One view at a time is enough for this project. The goal is to make a simple fullscreen app containing some basic components like lists and buttons to be used with a touchscreen interface. Wizard isn't quite an accurate description because one must be able to move between these views freely, not in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CardLayout is specifically appropriated when having various views you want to switch in between. Obviously, like @medoal says, JTabbedPane could also be used. Anyway, considering you want to use a CardLayout with buttons inside panels allowing you to change visible panel, what you would do could be :

1. Create your panels and allow them to have an object implementing a given interface registered. This interface would contain a method covering the [CardLayout#show(Container, String)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String)) method. Well, as an example, considering your panels all have their names set, and each of these names are different, you could write something like

   public interface PanelToggler {
        public void toggleTo(String name);
    }
2. In the class containing the CardLayout, you would implementing the PanelToggler with something like

   public void toggleTo(String name) {
       ((CardLayout) getLayout()).show(this, name);
   }

This way, in each panel, each button toggling viewed element from CardLayout would simply have to call toogleTo with the correct argument.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out perfectly for me. Is this a kind of standard pattern for implementing components which control stuff in the parent element? It seems to me that all the examples and tutorials are so small that they have all components and listeners instantiated in the same class so you don't really have to think of propagating the actions through to parent elements. Or can this be solved with totally different kind of architecture?

Comment: In fact, the problem with those sample is that they don't convey the complexity real application often have. In real life, pattern like the own I expose here (constructing a "mini" interface for the sole purpose of allowing children to gain control over parent) are often useful to allow minimum isolation between all components of UI. using this kind of pattern, you may get ironically called an "architect", but your code will always support easy refactoring (refactorings which are by far more common in UI development, as UI code is only a consequence of marketting choices).